# Jquery adds row to 2nd tr instead of 1st tr

Tags: jquery, html

I have jquery dynamically adding rows to a table, the jquery code is(simplified) as such :

```
var addTimeRow = function(id){
html = '<tr id="times_'+i+'">';             
html += '<td>';
html += '</td>';
html += '</tr>';
if( typeof id !== "undefined"){
        $('#times_'+id).after(html);
    }else{
        $('table').append(html);
    }
    $('#timestart').focus();
    i++;
}
```

My html is as such(simplified) :

```
    <table id="timestart">
    <?php foreach ( $invoice['InvoiceTime'] as $key=>$item){?>
    <tr id="times_<?php echo $key+1?>">
    <?php } ?>
    <?php }else{?>
    <tr id="times_1">
```

I have a button that adds the time :

```
<span class="add_time" id="add_icon_1"><button class="btn btn-success" type="button">+ Add Time</button></span>
```

Jquery button code :

```
$(document).on('click','.add_time',function(){
    var add_time_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var add_time_arr = add_time_id.split("_");
    var time_id = add_time_arr[add_time_arr.length-1];
    addTimeRow(time_id);
});
```

The code adds a row to the table, but does not add it where i want it to.  The way I would like it to work is when you click the add time button the output is as such :

```
<table>
<tr><-- Time added here at the beginning no matter what
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr><-- Previous added time
etc
```

Added Notes :

Delete Row is broken when following posted suggestions from Niet the Dark Absol:

```
$(".deletetime").on('click', function() {
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: Remove all that `if` block and just do `$('table').prepend(html);`?

Comment: do your add button ids increment or will they always be 1? Also looks like your code will genrate duplicate ids

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Ok, that breaks my delete button code somehow(ill post), and adds TWO rows to the beginning, instead of one...

Comment: to fix your delete button thing, do a delegated click event: `$('#timestart').on('click', '.deletetime', function() { ... `

Answer (score 0):

just use the `append` operation, like so:

```
$(function(){
  $('.tbody').append('<tr>TableDataHere</tr>');
})
```

It works properly and doesn't need anything like what you already have. I'm not 100% sure why you're using PHP(?). If I could guess at what you're trying to do, JQuery can do this in a cleaner and quicker way.

Comment: so right now I have 80 lines of code wrapped in html += "whatever"; would i just change all of that to be as above?  PHP is being used to call the data from the database - If data exists, display one way, otherwise display another way.

Comment: Yes! The `append` operation just adds the text specified in the argument as a child element of the accessed alement (in this case, `tbody`). And unless you're using a DB connection, you don't even need PHP

Comment: I am using a database connection :D Thanks, I will try!

Comment: Well I would suggest either inject the PHP data access, or just go to another method (Web API, ASP.NET MVC, etc.). Also please mark this and any future answers as such for future reference.

Comment: What are the benefits to Web API vs php, etc?

Comment: Web API's are cleaner and also more secure. PHP allows for SQL injection and insecure connections, whereas web API's are an app on their own and are preauthenticated using a key on the API side. Also, they are modular and more easy to manage. Instead of scrolling through hundreds of lines of code, you can pop open either project and modify it there. Ajax is also a reasonably new technology, allowing for future support. And finally, ASP.NET MVC allows for modular easy to maintain, secure code, using .NET and HTML, it is super easy to manage and maintain. Please see [here](http://www.asp.net).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111021/discussion-between-steven-and-rhyso).